# how to obtain activity locale in android?

Tags: android

i have made a multilingual application in android. On my language select activity i make the user select their language of preference. when the user selects i change the configuration of the application using the following code:

```
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
          getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

now before loading a activity i want to check whether the user has changed the locale or is it the same.
i want to get the activity's locale. i know how to get the application locale...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Add the following to your activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity 
    .....
    android:configChanges="locale"
    ....>
    .....
</activity>
```

The above will enable the application to update upon configuration changes in Language and Locale.

Use the Following java coding within your Activity class, preferably within onResume() and onCreate() methods.

```
 public class localeExample extends Activity {
            Locale l;

            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                l=new Locale();
                l=Locale.getDefault();
            }

            /** Called when the activity is resumed. */
            @Override
            protected void onResume(){
                super.onResume();
                l=new Locale();
                l=Locale.getDefault();
            }
}
```

Comment: once i have the local what do i do with it? don't i need to add to my configration? i am talking about the onResume() method....

Comment: What you wanted to do with the locale is upto you.. You asked how to get the locale of the activity and this is the answer for that.? This reads the default locale from the phone